# unable to use taskkill.exe from a java process

Tags: java, windows, taskkill

I need to kill an external process on windows (WindowsXP 32bit) from my integration test. I thought I'd just use 'taskkill.exe' but I cannot seem to get it working. Basically, every time I kick off a 'taskkill.exe' process from java it returns exit value -1073741515, nothing is printed to std error/output.

To reproduce the problem I wrote this simple application:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
    //In my real code, I kill process by its pid. However below also shows the problem:
    builder.command("taskkill.exe", "/?");
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = builder.start();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line = r.readLine();
    System.out.println("out:");
    while(line != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        line = r.readLine();
    }
    System.out.println(p.waitFor());
}
```

More data points:

- -1073741515 apparently means "The application failed to initialize properly". Not very helpful for me though ;)
- I've tried bunch of combinations of taskkill.exe parameters; I've tried prefixing the command with 'cmd', '/c'. Symptoms are exactly the same
- I tried executing other windows programs that live under windows\system32 and I also get -10737...
- Executing things like 'dir' or 'echo' works ok.

Any hints on what might be the problem?

Comment: I was able to terminate the process with your code - 
builder.command("taskkill.exe", "/pid", "2888"); 
and I got this msg on console -
out:
SUCCESS: The process with PID 2888 has been terminated.
0

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing your application as a different user? If you're running your app with a plain batch file in windows, right click and select `Run as administrator` and see the results. It's likely the account you're running under doesn't have enough rights to execute native apps.