# Is there any other way to run .exe from Java?

Tags: java, c++, gui-design

The main problem is that I cannot run my c++ logic by running it through Java; **am I creating a subprocess properly?**

Thank you all;
--- UPDATE! ---

So I have written these to test the ability to open .exe in the purest way; Eclipse can see the file/does not complain that it isn't there; ran using the run button in Eclipse:

The java file:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Runs_A_Exe {
   public static void main( String[] args ){
      try {
         ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( "M:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc\\ddd\\eee\\workspace\\Runs Simple Exe\\src\\executables\\a.exe" );
         Process p = pb.start();

         InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
         InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader( is );
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( isr );
         System.out.println( br.readLine() );
      }

      catch ( Exception e ) {
         System.out.println( e );
      }
   }
}
```

The c++ file:

```
#include <iostream>

int main( void ) {
   std::cout << "Hey!" << std::endl;
}
```

The output:

> null

Comment: If you're having problems with subprocesses producing blank files, ask about *that* problem rather than looking for yet another way to call your code from Java. Maybe the bug is in your C++ code (when running without an attached terminal, for instance).

Comment: @Greg but it works using command line

Comment: Yes, you said that. But it is still possible to write a program incorrectly in such a way that it works from the command line but doesn't when called from another process.

Comment: Or there could be other environment things (command paths, dynamic link path, exported variables, permissions) that change how the command line application is invoked.

Comment: My c++ program writes to stdout though... so is it not in the hands of the Java process that calls it?

Comment: @MichaelT I'm writing the Java part in Eclipse, might that be getting in the way?  ...if I use absolute paths to the executables, might that mitigate such external environment factors?

Comment: If the C++ program is writing to stdout rather than a file, java is getting the stdout rather than you redirecting it to a file.  This would leave an empty file in its place.

Comment: Hopefully I redirected it properly then; question updated!

Comment: I realize you've already developed this, but why write the logic in C++ and the GUI in Java? Why not just write the whole thing in Java, if you have to use Java for the GUI?

Comment: It was the client's request

Comment: The client requested that you implement the logic in C++ and thus have these integration problems? Weird.

Comment: When I run it, the output is "Hey!" What version of java are you using?

Comment: Oops, spoke too soon. I was running it from the command line. When I created an Eclipse project, I get "null".

Comment: It seems Eclipse uses jre and its own compiler, in which case I'm using jre1.7.0_51

Comment: If you add p.waitFor() to wait for the child process to complete, you can get the return value from it. In my case, it is returning -1073741515, which apparently means "The application failed to initialize properly." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534659/unable-to-use-taskkill-exe-from-a-java-process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process created by ProcessBuilder has standard input, output, and error streams, and if you do not write to its input stream or read from its output streams, it will hang. See the following questions for more information:

[Why does process hang if the parent does not consume stdout/stderr in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983372/why-does-process-hang-if-the-parent-does-not-consume-stdout-stderr-in-java)

[Java ProcessBuilder: Resultant Process Hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285408/java-processbuilder-resultant-process-hangs)

It is also possible that the process is never started because either the user it is running as doesn't have the necessary permissions to start it, or because some DLLs cannot be loaded, or possibly for some other reason.

[Unable to use taskkill.exe from a Java process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534659/unable-to-use-taskkill-exe-from-a-java-process)

I've created a modified version of your program. When I run it from the command line it is able to execute the exe file, but when I do the same from an Eclipse project, the process returns an exit code of -1073741515, which, according to the question above, means "The application failed to initialize properly." I think you need to investigate the environment in which Eclipse is invoking java to run your exe (what user it runs under, how the PATH is set up, etc.), and whether all dependencies of the exe are available (what DLLs does it depend on) to determine why it isn't running successfully.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

public class Runs_An_Exe {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("c:/cygwin/tmp/a.exe");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true); // redirect stderr to stdin
        Process p = pb.start();

        final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
        // capture all output from the process
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                readAll(isr, writer);
            }
        }).start();
        // wait for it to finish, and display the exit code
        int result = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("result: " + result);
        // display any output from the process
        System.out.println(writer.toString());
    }

    private static void readAll(Reader reader, Writer writer) {
        try {
            char[] buffer = new char[8192];
            int n = 0;
            while (-1 != (n = reader.read(buffer))) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

(The a.exe I used was compiled from your C++ source in the question using g++ 4.8.2 under 32-bit Cygwin.)

Answer (score 2):

Are you calling it with the right arguments? Does the C++ has the right working directory? Is Java parsing the stdout correctly? If you only do an hello world in the C++, can you see it in Java?

I suggest starting back from the beginning, make it work with the simplest possible C++ program and slowly complexify the C++ (putting back in your logic)

- First call an hello world from java, and ensure the output is read correctly in Java
- Then add a few arguments and ensure that the output is read correctly in java,
- Then add a bit of logic, and ensure that the output is read correctly from Java.

And make sure the C++ is *alway* working correctly with Java. Write automated tests if you can :)

---

What happened is that you committed the capital sin of not having an end-to-end integrated build of your application from the beginning. The pain you feel is you expiating your crime :P .

I'm kidding of course, but seriously, next time, I would suggest integrating the C++ as soon as you can! Its those integration points that are always a source of problem in any software (I would know). Solving them early is a great way to ensure that you can focus on the logic later on. If I could suggest a reading, check out [Growing object oriented software guided by test](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_10?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=growing%20object-oriented%20software%20guided%20by%20tests&sprefix=growing+ob%2Caps%2C234&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Agrowing%20object-oriented%20software%20guided%20by%20tests), it's a great demonstration of this kind of approach.

Comment: Just tested it with a simple hello.cpp: no arguments; absolute directory/Eclipse did not complain about not finding the file; I'm having the code above handle the stdout for me, which has not been called out as wrong thus far... and the hello.cpp still does nothing...

Comment: Weird, try calling a system level exe first, like `dir`. Maybe Java doesn't complain but is still not working. Check the return code with `waitFor`. Is it 0? Change the C++, do a `return 1` at the end of main. Does it change the value of `waitFor` in Java? If no, you may not call the right process. Do `pb.redirectErrorStream(true);` before creating the process. Is an error line appearing?